# How to upload an image into a data base and display it back to the view ASP.NET Core MVC

Tags: c#, asp.net-core-mvc, image-upload

Data classes EF core
`

```
 public class Manga
    {
        public int Id { get; set; }
        public string Name { get; set; }
        public string Description { get; set; }
        public DateTime? DateCreated { get; set; }
        public DateTime? Updated { get; set; }
        public byte[] Image { get; set; }
        //Manga can have many chapters
        public ICollection<Chapter> Chapters { get; set; }
    }
    public class Chapter
    {
        public int Id { get; set; }
        public string Name { get; set; }
        public string Description { get; set; }
        public DateTime? DateCreated { get; set; }
        public DateTime? Updated { get; set; }
        public byte[] Image { get; set; }
        //Chapter can only have manga
        public Manga Manga { get; set; }
        //The chapter connected to the manga
        public int MangaId { get; set; }
    }
```

`I am trying to learn how to upload images and files. Right image is a priority. I want to allow users to upload images and be used publicly. I am using the binary array method. Is it a bad idea? What is better if this is a no go.

While working on this I am getting a model error:

> The value 'narutotest.jpg' is not valid for Image

My code:

```
[HttpPost]
[ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
public async Task<IActionResult> Create([Bind("Id,Name,Description,Image")] Manga manga, List<IFormFile> Image)
{
    if (ModelState.IsValid)
    {
        foreach (var item in Image)
        {
            if(item.Length > 0)
            {
                using (var stream = new MemoryStream())
                {
                    await item.CopyToAsync(stream);
                    manga.Image = stream.ToArray();
                }
            }
        }

        manga.DateCreated = DateTime.Now;
        manga.Updated = DateTime.Now;
        _context.Add(manga);
        await _context.SaveChangesAsync();
        return RedirectToAction(nameof(Index));
    }

    return View(manga);
}
```

View:

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-4">
        <form asp-action="Create">
            <div asp-validation-summary="ModelOnly" class="text-danger"></div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <label asp-for="Name" class="control-label"></label>
                <input asp-for="Name" class="form-control" />
                <span asp-validation-for="Name" class="text-danger"></span>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <label asp-for="Description" class="control-label"></label>
                <input asp-for="Description" class="form-control" />
                <span asp-validation-for="Description" class="text-danger"></span>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <label asp-for="Image" class="control-label"></label>
                <input asp-for="Image" type="file" id="files" />
                <span asp-validation-for="Image" class="text-danger"></span>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <input type="submit" value="Create" class="btn btn-primary" />
            </div>
        </form>
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You should provide more details such as `Manga` struct . But there are two things you should firstly notice . Firstly , in order to support file uploads, HTML forms must specify an `enctype` of `multipart/form-data` . The second thing is you should move `_context.Add(manga)` into the `foreach` file loop , loop the files , read to stream , save to `Manga` class , add/trace into context and at last call `context.SaveChangesAsync()` to save into database outside of the loop .

Comment: Hello thank you very much for responding and I apologies for late reply. I have added the datacontext classes that you asked for. Also if you could provide more info on what would be best way to complete the task i am trying to achive. I am very much not experienced so if you could give as much steps and details as possible.